# How do you add a scrollbar to a box of information?

Tags: html, css

I am not very good at html and this may seem like an easy thing to do, but I need to add a scroll bar to a box of information.

The coding for the box looks like this:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="title">Doctor Who</a>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <div class="text-container">
            <IMG SRC="https://31.media.tumblr.com/dea38d2e07dc5ef0a30adbc213f4eda0/tumblr_inline_mxq54ba4yx1qhpvm6.gif" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100>
            <br>
            <br>
            <IMG SRC="https://31.media.tumblr.com/f5d7e9e7d802697bb948811a79d0c0ba/tumblr_inline_mxq627yuKg1qhpvm6.gif" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on the website page it looks like icons in a box and there are multiple boxes on the page each including many different icons.  The problem is, the icons take up too much room in the boxes so I wanted to add a scrollbar to each box so that all the icons and boxes will fit nicely on the screen.

Any help is appreciated and because I am a noob please don't make it to complicated for me.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Use `overflow:scroll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set address the overflow of your element

```
#box{
width:XXpx;
height:XXpx;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

That will place a scroll bar in your box